# Load the root view when app enter into background in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, uinavigationcontroller, background

I am developing an application which has 4 views and use navigation controller to navigate through. The first view is login interface. I just want to display login view when user press home button from second view. I have tried to use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. This does not work. Because I need to do this job only user press home button from second view (Second view contains MKMapView).

Can you please let me know what is the best option for this job? Basically I just need to check what view I am currently on.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log a BOOL variable that the viewDidAppear function on your second controller sets to YES. And when you leave that view set it to NO.  In applicationDidEnterForeground check it.  If it is YES then the user left while in the second view.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is a good way of tracking which view am I on now when application enter into suspend. But what method do I have to use to load root view?

Comment: `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` should do it.  You may need to call this from your viewController.

Comment: I am sorry for delayed response. If need to call popToRootViewControllerAnimated from my viewController, how my viewController does know when enter into background. I can not use viewDidUnload or viewDidDisappear. Because that will be called when moving to another view. 
Cheers